# What is the word for someone who sees music as colours?

Tags: colors, music

Some people visualise specific musical keys or chords as specific colours. There is a name for this, which I think starts with *chromo-*. Am I remembering this correctly?

Comment: ["Perfect pitch"](http://xenophilius.wordpress.com/2008/11/30/what-color-is-middle-c-musical-pitch-related-to-color/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The general term is [*synesthesia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesthesia), for any combination of senses (laymen also sometimes speak of "intersensoriality"), and *sound-color synesthesia*, or [*chromesthesia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromesthesia), for sounds and colors in particular.

> **Chromesthesia** or **sound to color synesthesia** is a type of synesthesia in which heard sounds automatically and involuntarily evoke an experience of color

Answer (score 5):

[***chromesthesia***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesthesia#Sound_.E2.86.92_color_synesthesia) is a specific form of the general *synesthesia* and is a neurological condition in which stimulation of one sensory or cognitive pathway leads to automatic, involuntary experiences in a second sensory or cognitive pathway.